# Calculating Past 90 days from GetDate()-1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

How should I modify my code to prevent the displaying of current date's data?

I need the `Getdate() -1` for previous day, then the past 90 days from that revised date.  The 90 days should start from yesterday not current date.

Something like this, however, this still displays current date:

```
WHERE CAST([CREATE_DTG] AS DATE) 
       BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(day, -90, CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()) as DATE)) 
       AND CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()) as DATE)
```

My current attempt returns error msg on the `And`.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
WHERE CAST([CREATE_DTG] AS DATE) BETWEEN cast(getdate() - 91 as date) 
    and cast(getdate() - 1 as date)
```

Comment: wouldn't the getdate()-91 still start from the current dayand not previous day?

Comment: @KarenSchaefer That's why it is 91 and not 90 :)

Comment: Sorry still confused when which actual date would it be calculating from.
thanks for the input, however, if I am still reading this correctly the calculation for the past 90 days starts with current date.  I need the past 90 days to start from the previous day(4/26/2016) from the getdate() value (4/27/2016)

Current date = 4/27/2016
Previous Date = 4/26/2016

the 90 days should start from Previous Date(4/26/2016).  I hope this clarifies things.